# Why does my while loop let me continuously enter values, but the loop does nothing

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iosteam>

int main(){
int money, coupons, chocolate, ogCoupons, newChocolate, couponsUsed;

std :: cout << "How many chocolate bars do you want to buy? " << std :: endl;
std :: cin >> money;

coupons = money;
chocolate = money;
ogCoupons = coupons;

std :: cout << "\nYou got " << coupons << " coupons." << std :: endl;


while(coupons >= 6)
    {
        coupons -= 6;
        couponsUsed = (ogCoupons - coupons); //I think problem lies here
        chocolate++;
        newChocolate = couponsUsed;
        coupons += newChocolate;
        ogCoupons = coupons;
    } 

std :: cout << "\nYou have " << coupons << " coupons left and " <<  chocolate << " chocolate bars." << std :: endl;

return 0;
}
```

Code it supposed to do this: If you have 22 dollars, you can initially buy 22 chocolate bars.  This will give you 22 coupons.  You can redeem 18 of them for 3 additional chocolate bars, for a total now of 25.  These 3 additional bars gives you 3 additional coupons, for a total of 7 now.  This gives you enough coupons to buy one more chocolate bar, with one more coupon, for a total now of 26 chocolate bars and 2 left over coupons.

The problem lies withing the while loop. When I try to subtract the two variables in couponsUsed the loop lets me input random integers and character, but nothing happens.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Tip: You don't need to space out the `std` prefix. Just do `std::cin`, etc. What you have here looks really odd. Additionally, try and declare variables when you need them, not in a pile up front, as in `int coupons = money`. This makes it very clear what the variable is, and that it is *absolutely* initialized. In C++ uninitialized variables are an absolute nightmare, and you want it to be completely obvious which are initialized.

Comment: You only use `cin` once, so why are claiming that the program lets you "continuously enter values"?  I think you're just typing the data into your terminal but its not going anywhere.  Your question should include a small but complete shell session showing all input you gave to the program and all the output it gave to you, along with a clear description of why you think the output is wrong and what you would expect instead.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but none of the stream insertions needs the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. Just use `'\n'` to end a line.

Comment: Your `coupons +=` line *always* has the effect of setting `coupons` back to the value of `ogCoupons` because of the way you coded it.  This causes an infinite loop.  Use a debugger or just print the value of every variable as the program runs to debug.

Comment: Just a note on the problem itself: you can solve this without a loop at all. `x` dollars will get you `x + ((x - 1) / 5)` chocolates with `x % 5 == 0 ? 5 : x % 5` coupons leftover (not possible to be left with 0 coupons).

Answer (score 4):

Your code is confusing. Maybe think of it this way:

```
while (coupons >= 6) {
     // So far, so good. If we're in this loop, we have enough
     // coupons to trade for a chocolate bar. So buy exactly one:
     ++chocolate;
     coupons -= 6;

     // And because we bought a chocolate bar, we get one more coupon:
     ++coupons;
}
```

I didn't test it, but that's a lot easier to read and make sense of. Give it a try.

A common error in programming is to make the problem too complicated. If things stop making sense, then back away and ask if you're keeping it simple.

Also, it's better to define variables when you're about to use them. You define a bunch of variables at the top of your function that you ultimately don't really need, or if you do, only within the loop. So declare them where you use them. I'd write the top more like this:

```
int money;

std :: cout << "How many chocolate bars do you want to buy? " << std :: endl;
std :: cin >> money;

// Chocolate bars are $1, so we get 1 bar per dollar
// and 1 coupon for each bar we buy.
int coupons = money;
int chocolate = money;
```

And you flat out don't need the other variables.

Comment: You're good to go. https://onlinegdb.com/OvcvuSilf9

Comment: "There are two ways of constructing a software design: One way is to make it so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies, and the other way is to make it so complicated that there are no obvious deficiencies. The first method is far more difficult." -Tony Hoare